# background-size:cover relative to content when resizing browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, css-position

I'm a newbie of responsive design and bootstrap. My website template background is a few circle with a lot of things inside, so i can't draw it with css, it must be background-image.
Now i need to make text, stick and background image fit together when resizing window like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFo80.jpg
How can i do that?
**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="row row1">
        <div class="col-xs-9">
          <div class="square"></div>
          <hr class="path">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <h3>Text1</h3>
        </div>
      </div><!--end row-->
      <div class="row row2">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <h3>Text2</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
          <div class="square"></div>
          <hr class="path">
        </div>
      </div><!--end row-->
      <div class="row row3">
        <div class="col-xs-9">
          <div class="square"></div>
          <hr class="path">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <h3>Text3</h3>
        </div>
      </div><!--end row-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body.issue {
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/IFo4wAt.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #ccc;
}
body.issue h3 {
  font-size: 3em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
}
.circle {
  width: 650px !important;
  height: 650px;
  border-radius: 325px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 325px;
  -moz-border-radius: 325px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ff0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.square {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 12px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 12px;
  position: absolute;
}
.path {
  width: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
}
.row1, .row2 {height: 35vh}
.row3 {height: 30vh}
.row1 .path {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(330deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(330deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(330deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(330deg);
  transform: rotate(330deg);
  right: -30px;
  top: 158px;
}
.row1 .square {
  right: 96px;
  top: 182px;
}
.row1 h3 {
  top: 90px;
  left: 30px;
}
.row2 .path {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(10deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(10deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(10deg);
  transform: rotate(10deg);
  left: 12px;
  top: 48px;
}
.row2 .square {
  left: 145px;
  top: 50px;
}
.row2 h3 {top: 5px;right: 0}
.row3 .path {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(35deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(35deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(35deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(35deg);
  transform: rotate(35deg);
  right: -55px;
  top: 55px;
}
.row3 .square {
  right: 70px;
  top: 0;
}
.row3 h3 {
  left: 55px;
  top: 80px;
}
```

Here's my code:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iqFyd
Thank you and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Why can't it be CSS?

Comment: You can use a responsive image map, find the coordinates, and see if that works. Amazing how many people ask about doing something like this, if they knew anything about CSS, there's nothing that sticks to background size cover and sizes down with it in the same position. You can make various different background sizes for different breakpoints and then make media queries that fake this.